VIM autocommand on executable files
I want to run a VIM command only on loading of executable files (specifically, what I want, is to add a button to the menu bar, that will run the script, aka call :!%)
The question, of course is for non-windows based systems (like linux), where I cannot tell if a file is executable by its name (but by running ls -l)
Is there a way to do it with autocmd? Or any other way?

You can do a lot of things with autocommands but I am not sure what you are asking. How to determine if a file is executable in a portable way? How to use autocommands? Something else?

You cannot do that on Unix/Linux without first recognizing if the file is executable. So the way to implement what you want is: run an autocommand (BufReadPost, I think) on opening every file, check if it's executable. To check: use builtin function executable() with the full path of the current file. Try:
:echo executable(expand('%:p'))


When writing scripts, you would usually put a shebang on the first line to specify the interpreter to use.
This is generally considered good practice and will remove any ambiguity on which program will run the script.
While a script may work without a shebang in a specific environment, it won't be portable.
Also see this answer to What is the default shebang if none is specified in a python script?.
Let's assume you're doing the right thing and start your script with a shebang.
You can make use of it by checking if the first two characters of the buffer equal #!.
The following autocommand that will print either "executable" or "not executable" depending on the presence of a shebang:
augroup executable_script
    autocmd!
    autocmd BufEnter * echo getline(1)[:1]=='#!'?'executable':'not executable'
augroup END

It uses the getline() function to get the first line of the buffer. Its first two characters (yes, ranges are inclusive) are compared to the string '#!' and a ternary will return the resulting string to :echo.
For reference, see :help getline(), :help sublist, and :help ternary.

Shell scripts do not require shebang. An executable text file without shebang will be interpreted by /bin/sh.

@phd thanks for pointing out my mistake. I think the user's login shell (which may be different from /bin/sh) is used, isn't it? I'll try to think of an edit.

"I think the user's login shell (which may be different from /bin/sh) is used, isn't it?" Echoing $SHELL is not enough as it will echo from the current environment. Let's recognize the very shell (Linux-specific way): $ echo 'readlink /proc/$$/exe' > test; $ chmod u+x test; $ ./test -> /usr/bin/bash With any shebang (like #!/bin/dash) it prints the shell from the shebang. Without shebang it prints the current shell (not the login shell); I tried with bash and dash as the current shells.

@phd greatly appreciate your help. I tried to come up with something that's at least not completely wrong.
